# Error in starting rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently fromatted my Windows machine and installed `ruby` and `rubyonrails`. When I create a new rails project using `rails new FirstApp` it works fine, but when I try to start the rails server using `rails s` it throws me the below mentioned error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0.beta1/l
ib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:70:in `rescue in find_zone!': uninitial
ized constant TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:55:in `find_zone!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:20:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/application.rb:285:in `initialize!'
        from E:/rubydemo/test3/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/rubydemo/test3/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from E:/rubydemo/test3/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from E:/rubydemo/test3/config.ru:in `new'
        from E:/rubydemo/test3/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0
.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me understand the problem here and how to resolve it?
I am using `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]` and `Rails 4.1.0.beta1`

Comment: maybe you should use a stable rails version, and not a beta.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713472/uninitialized-constant-tzinfoinvalidtimezoneidentifier-nameerror-rails-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, got rid of the issue.
Make sure to add `gem 'tzinfo'` to your Gemfile before the `tzinfo-data` entry and everything will start working.
Ref: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13553

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a problem on Windows. Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713472/uninitialized-constant-tzinfoinvalidtimezoneidentifier-nameerror-rails-4) that might help you out. Hope this helps.