# Rails error on starting new server: invalid timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a new install of Ruby 2.4.1 and Rails 5.0.2 on Linux. After creating a new Rails project, I get the following errors after running "rails server":

```
/home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:98:in `rescue in find_zone!': Invalid Timezone: UTC (ArgumentError)
        from /home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:81:in `find_zone!'
        from /home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:25:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/___/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/___/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
...
```

This looks similar to a problem that [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780242/error-in-starting-rails-server) [Windows users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713472/uninitialized-constant-tzinfoinvalidtimezoneidentifier-nameerror-rails-4) had a while back, but I tried the [fix suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713472/uninitialized-constant-tzinfoinvalidtimezoneidentifier-nameerror-rails-4?answertab=votes#tab-top) (adding "require 'tzinfo'" to environment.rb), and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in `application.rb` that the command: `config.time_zone` is being run. If it is not, try adding the following line:

`config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` (in `application.rb'`.)

Let me know if that solves it!

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. `config.time_zone` wasn't being run. Once I ran it inside the Application class, the server started up fine.

Comment: glad to be of help